# Python OS doesn't see variables

Tags: python, operating-system, pysimplegui

I'm currently developing an app that allows the user to install .apk files on their FireTV using a PC. I'm currently having issues regarding OS: it doesn't see variables (I've tried using `format` and normal).

Here is my code:

```
while True:
    event, values = window.read()

    ip = values["-IP-"]
    path = values ["-PATH-"]
    
    if event == pyg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        exit()

    if event == 'Start':
        os.system(f'adb push {ip} {path}')
```

Comment: Didn't show variables ? should paste what the failures. IMO, maybe you don't have new `f-string` feature in your python. From python 3.6, PEP 498 introduces a new kind of string literals: f-strings, or formatted string literals.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
`if event == 'Start':
    cmd = "ls -{0} -{1}".format(ip, path)
    os.system(cmd)`
```